# Need a cache friendly data structure to store the neighbors of a letter in a 2d-array

Tags: c++, c, performance, caching, optimization

Assume the following is a 2d array that we are operating on

```
a b c d
e f g h
i j k l
m n o p
```

The surrounding neighbor of 'f' are [a b c e g i j k]. I'm trying to create a cache friendly data structure to store the neighbor of a node. Right now I have something like so

```
struct Neighbor{
   size_t neighborPosition[8][2];
   size_t size;
};

typedef size_t Position[2];
typedef Neighbor** NeighborTable;
```

Note that the max neighbor a node could have is 8.  Anyone have any advice? I need the structure to be a constant time neighbor lookup so I will be pre-calculating the neighbor of  each node.

Comment: If you have a regular grid with known dimensions, then the most cache-friendly representation is *not* pre-calculating the neighbors. You can still calculate the neighbors in constant time, and it will probably be faster than looking up the answers.

Comment: I agree with @JohnCalsbeek . This is pretty common in image processing. Used to find objects in images for example.

Comment: yepp, branching is still a lot better than waiting for a read from main memory... if it's in the line cache then a lookup could be fine, but that would mean that your table is not so large, so why optimize it?

Comment: @JohnCalsbeek: The grid size can vary. This is for a boggle solver program. So if I don't precalculate it then I would have to calculate the neighbors of a node many times

Comment: The grid size is, however, *known*. Your single piece of data describing the size of the grid is much easier to keep around than a list of adjacencies. If you're trying to make this cache-friendly, then you'd want to just store the size and recalculate the neighbors (going to memory is orders of magnitude slower than calculation on current architectures). However, for Boggle, I would be shocked if you measure a performance difference either way. Just do what produces the least code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every cell has the same neighbors, in terms of their relative location, except for the edge cells.  But if you add a border (an extra row & column at the start and end), and fill it with a value that lets you know it is a border, the you don't need any data structure at all to identify neighbors.

Comment: That's not a bad idea, I might try that, but having a list would be more convenient though